# Python MYSQL SELECT with dynamic value

Tags: python, mysql

I have a query function where I want to place the value dynamically in.

```
query_values = {
    "column_value": question["value"],
    "value_2": question["value_2"],
    "startdate": date_range["start"],
    "enddate": date_range["end"]
}

query = (
        "SELECT %(column_value)s FROM ga_ad_matched_query "
        "WHERE (ga_ad_matched_query LIKE %(value_2)s) AND "
        "(stat_date BETWEEN %(enddate)s AND %(startdate)s)"
    )
cur.execute(query, query_values)
```

All works well but if I use the %(column_values) variable I get the content of question["value"] into the result and not the actual values behind the column. If I don't use the %(column_values) variable but use the regular name of the column insted, everything works out fine. ....but it need this function dynamically so I need to place %(column_values) there.

Is there a Syntax mistake i oversee here?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is not possible to use column names as query parameters. You will have to either try and escape column names yourself, and insert it in the raw query (potentially dangerous), or retrieve all columns, and then use just some of them (I would do it that way).

Comment: @lovasoa Thanks for your solution. Works geat!

Answer (score -1):

try using the more straightforward query as a string syntax:

```
query = "SELECT %s FROM ga_ad_matched_query WHERE (ga_ad_matched_query LIKE %s) AND (stat_date BETWEEN %s AND %s)" % (colum_value, value2, enddate, startdate)
cur.execute(query)
```

Comment: It is HIGHLY DISCOURAGED to use string templating for creating database queries.

Comment: @lovasoa do you have any better solution for the Problem?

Comment: Yes, I added a comment to your question.

Comment: @lovasoa totally agree with you, just giving OP a starting point to check if the rest of his query is valid or not. later you can go back in and harden your queries, make sure queries are indexed, etc.  i usually don't write production-ready code when i'm prototyping. but yes, you're right.

Comment: Having an application vulnerable to SQL injections is not just a detail you can work around at conception time. In this case, the code just has to be thought in another way, because it is not possible to use column names at query parameters.